# What is the purpose of Type Inference in c#

Tags: c#, type-inference

I don't see exactly what is the purpose of type inference, what is the benefit from adding that to the language, is there any special use like the in C++11 auto keyword?

I see it just like an add since I don't know really situation where the resulting type is not necessarily known in advance

(I mean the use of keyword var)

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/257450/why-is-type-inference-useful)

Comment: It makes anonymous types possible. And it saves a lot of typing.

Comment: i'm looking to that, thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type inference saves an *incredible* amount of typing when dealing with complex signatures.  For instance,

```
var itemCreator = _interface.GetItemCreator();
```

is so much more compact and readable than

```
Func<int, string, double, decimal, 
    Dictionary<int, KeyValuePair<int, string>>, 
    Action<string, string, string>> itemCreator = _interface.GetItemCreator();
```

This is obviously an incredibly contrived example designed to prove a point...that code gets messy and the type declarations that go with it are also often messy.  Type Inference saves us a bit of pain on that front.

In addition, Type Inference gives us the ability to use anonymous methods which are used heavily in LINQ and serialization libraries.

Anonymous methods generate a type at compile time.  As a result, there is no way for you to declare the type appropriately ahead of time.

As far as your comparison to the auto operator in C++ 11, at first glance it appears to have the same/similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Method1() 
    {
        return "string";
    }
}

// Calling code
Class1 cls1 = new Class1();
var result = cls1.Method1(); // result is string type.
```

Now some time later you decide you needed to return *int* from your Method1. You can do so without having to worry about the calling code.

Apart from this *var* is also heavily used in LINQ.

Another use would be to make your code cleaner, for example:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

vs.

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

You can see which one is cleaner to read.

Answer (score 1):

Type inference helps with at least three aspects of C# development:

1. **Writing code**

   `var` requires fewer keystrokes, and less time worrying about the exact types returned from methods, etc.
2. **Understanding code**

   `var` produces more concise, readable code than explicitly specifying types.
3. **Maintaining code**

   Fewer code changes are needed in fewer places when the types in your application change (and they will).

`var` has many benefits and few drawbacks.  I use it everywhere unless I have a compelling reason not to.